# Reverse fixed menu animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

The menu is currently set up so that when you open a page it is visible at the bottom of the page. As you scroll up the black menu panel will disappear out of view then reappear with the logo from the top.

Is there a way to reverse it so that once you scroll back up the black menu will disappear and reappear at the bottom of the page?

[see website by clicking here](http://bluebabooncreative.com/rossopomodoro2/index_.html)

```
        var distance = $('#content-div').offset().top,
            $window = $(window);
            var didscroll=true;
        $window.scroll(function() {
            if(didscroll==true){
            if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
                didscroll = false;
                //alert("r");
                // Your div has reached the top
                jQuery('.header').css({"position":"fixed","top":'-100px',"left":0});
                jQuery('a.logo').css("visibility","visible");
                 jQuery( ".header" ).slideDown( 5000, function() {
                     jQuery(this).css({"top":0});

                 });
            }
            }
        });

        });
```

Comment: Please post some code sir.

Comment: Just add an else condition and do the opposite of what you did.

Comment: where would I put the else condition?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline styles when you reached the breakpoint. Like this

```
if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
   $(".header").attr({style : ""});
   $("a.logo").attr({style : ""});
}
```

Comment: No that stop the menu from appearing (with the logo) as you scroll down the page. As you scroll back up the menu should disppear at the top of the page before reappearing in the right position (beneath the bouncing arrow)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
var oritop = -100;
$(window).scroll(function() { //on scroll,
    var scrollt = window.scrollY; //get the amount of scrolling
    var elm = $(".box"); //get the box we want to make sticky
    if(oritop < 0) {
        oritop= elm.offset().top; //cache the original top offset
    }
    if(scrollt >= oritop) { //if you scrolled past it,
        //make it sticky or else
    }
    else { //otherwise
        //Do what you want to
    }
});
```